# Who is allowed to fix bugs in ros_comm (and other WG) stacks?

Tags: ros, ros-comm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that help of rossrv erroneously refers to rosmsg.

It should say:

rossrv is a command-line tool for displaying information about ROS Service types.

instead of:

**rosmsg** is a command-line tool for displaying information about ROS **Message** types.

Also all references in fullhelp to message should be changed to service:

```
  rossrv show Show message description
  rossrv list List all messages
  rossrv md5  Display message md5sum
  rossrv package    List messages in a package
  rossrv packages   List packages that contain messages
```

The simple fix is to make a change in this file: [https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/changeset/16304/stacks/ros_comm/trunk/tools/rosmsg/src/rosmsg/**init**.py](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/changeset/16304/stacks/ros_comm/trunk/tools/rosmsg/src/rosmsg/__init__.py)

Instead of this:

```
def fullusage(cmd):
"""
:param cmd: command name, ``str``
:returns: usage text for cmd, ``str``
"""
return """rosmsg is a command-line tool for displaying information about ROS Message types.
Commands:
\t%(cmd)s show\tShow message description
\t%(cmd)s list\tList all messages
\t%(cmd)s md5\tDisplay message md5sum
\t%(cmd)s package\tList messages in a package
\t%(cmd)s packages\tList packages that contain messages
```

Do something like this:

```
def fullusage(cmd):
"""
:param cmd: command name, ``str``
:returns: usage text for cmd, ``str``
"""
if cmd == "rosmsg":
    type_string = "Message"
else:
    type_string = "Service"   

    return """%(cmd)s is a command-line tool for displaying information about ROS %(type_string)s types.

Commands:
\t%(cmd)s show\tShow %(type_string)s description
\t%(cmd)s list\tList all %(type_string)ss
\t%(cmd)s md5\tDisplay %(type_string)s md5sum
\t%(cmd)s package\tList %(type_string)ss in a package
\t%(cmd)s packages\tList packages that contain %(type_string)ss
```

My question is what is the way to proceed:

a) I need to create bug, submit apatch, get it reviewed, etc. or

b) Ask A Willow Garage employee to commit this fix, or

c) I should leave things as is as not important.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35660/who-is-allowed-to-fix-bugs-in-ros_comm-(and-other-wg)-stacks?/) by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 901 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

a) If you create a bug ticket and attach the patch, someone will almost certainly fix it fairly quickly.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on 2012-06-04**:
The question remains does it have to be "someone to fix it" or can it be me?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-05**:
By "fix it" I just meant apply your patch. If you want commit access to the repository, go to https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/ and click on "Request to join project".